# mapping the true or false values to active inactive in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on test application for student records. I am displaying it in html table grid. However i would like to convert the value like True or False to active/inactive. Also 0 or 1 value to male/female.

**DB**

```
    [Id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
    [RollNo]      INT           NOT NULL,
    [Address]     VARCHAR (200) NOT NULL,
    [Sex]         INT           NOT NULL,
    [Active]      BIT           NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

**Model**

```
public class Student
    {
        public Student();

        public bool? Active { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RollNo { get; set; }
        public int Sex { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-responsive table-hover" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Student Name</th>
                    <th>Student Roll No</th>
                    <th>Student Sex</th>
                    <th>Student Address</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Students)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.StudentName</td>
                        <td>@item.RollNo</td>
                        <td>@item.Sex</td>
                        <td>@item.Address</td>
                        <td>@item.Active</td>
                    </tr>
                }


            </tbody>

        </table>
```

**Controller**

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            SchoolDbEntities db = new SchoolDbEntities();
            StudentVM vm = new StudentVM();
            vm.Students = db.Students.ToList();
            return View(vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator

```
 <td>@(item.Active ? "Active" : "InActive")</td>
 <td>@(item.Sex==1 ? "Female" : "Male")</td>
```

If the `Active` property is nullable bool, you need to check the property for null before doing the value comparison.

```
<td>
    @if (item.Active!= null)
    {
        @(item.Active.Value ? Html.Raw("Active") : Html.Raw("InActive"))
    }
</td>
```

The above code will render Active or Inactive based on the value Active property value if it not `NULL`. If it is `NULL` , It will not print anything.

You can perhaps move this to a helper method so that your view is much cleaner.

Edit : *As per your comment, you want*

> if null or false then 'InActive" else "Active"

You can simply add a null check before checking the value for 'True`

```
<td>@(item.Active!=null && item.Active.Value ? "Active" : "InActive")</td>
```

Comment: here the Active is nullable type, so it says "Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'.". So we cannot set it directly

Comment: What you want to display if the Active property value is `NULL` ? empty text ?

Comment: if null or false then  'InActive" else "Active"

Answer (score 1):

Just putting the field value:

> ```
> <td>@item.Sex</td>
> ```

will just call `ToString()` on the value. But you can include an arbitrary expression:

```
<td>@(item.Sex == 0 ? "Male" : "Female")</td>
```

(Handling other values beyond 0 and 1 will require a more complex expression, perhaps in a helper function in your model type.)

This can be used with booleans as well:

```
<td>@(item.Acive ? "Active" : "Inactive")</td>
```